# kendo external template binded to a grid

Tags: kendo-ui

```
        <fieldset  id="trans">

            <legend>Transaction info

            </legend>
            <table>

                <tr class="PickListItem">
                    <td>Issued By:</td>
                    <td>#= ActionInitiatedBy #</</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Exp Date Override:</td>
                    <td>#=ExpDateOverridden #</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>billing Status:</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Bill Batch Date:</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Refunded:</td>
                    <td> #=RefundedDate#</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Refunded By:</td>
                    <td>#=RefundedBy#</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            Note:
                        <br />
                            #= Note#

                        </div>



                    </td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>

                            #if ("#= Refunded #" == 'no'   )
                            {#
                            <div>
                                    <label>Refund Amount : $ #= PatronChargeAmount #</label>    &nbsp;   <a onclick="Refund(' #= ActionHistory_id # ')" class="k-button">Refund?</a>

                            </div>

                            #}#


                    </td>

                </tr>
            </table>

        </fieldset>
```

I am new to MVC & kendo controls.
The conditional statement is not erroring, but the div never shows. what am I doing wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is incorrect! You wrote: `<td>#= ActionInitiatedBy #</</td>` (there is an extra `</`). It should be `<td>#= ActionInitiatedBy #</td>`.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed your condition is not correct - [check the documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/templates/overview)

It should be something like this

```
<td>
            #if (Refunded == 'no'){#
                        <div>
                           <label>Refund Amount : $ #= PatronChargeAmount #</label>    &nbsp;   <a onclick="Refund(' #= ActionHistory_id # ')" class="k-button">Refund?</a>
                        </div>
            #}#
</td>
```